# After updating to the latest Redux Dev Tools extension I am getting: "Symbol.observable as defined by Redux and Redux DevTools do not match."

Tags: javascript, redux, google-chrome-extension, redux-devtools, redux-devtools-extension

For some unknown issue after getting the latest update from the redux dev tools chrome extension I am getting the below warning message:

> Symbol.observable as defined by Redux and Redux DevTools do not match.
> This could cause your app to behave differently if the DevTools are
> not loaded. Consider polyfilling Symbol.observable before Redux is
> imported or avoid polyfilling Symbol.observable altogether.

[image: Symbol Observable Error Message]

By reading the error message I am understanding that redux and redux dev tools should use the same Symbol.observable but they are not. It is very weird though as I haven't changed anything within my code and I am using the code as per [documentation](https://github.com/zalmoxisus/redux-devtools-extension#13-use-redux-devtools-extension-package-from-npm).

My question is if you have any clue on which direction should I go? Is this a chrome extension bug that we just need to report?

I am using latest chrome extension with name [Redux DevTools](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/redux-devtools/lmhkpmbekcpmknklioeibfkpmmfibljd/related?hl=en). I've noticed that if I uninstall the chrome dev-tool extension this warning message is not appearing anymore.

My code looks like this:

```
  // The redux-devtools-extension is renamed to this npm package
  import { composeWithDevTools } from "@redux-devtools/extension"; 

  // Some code here ...

  const composeEnhancersPersonalProject = composeWithDevTools({
    name: `My Project`,
  });

  // Some other code here ...
  
  const myStore = createStore(
    persistedReducer,
    composeEnhancersPersonalProject(
      applyMiddleware(serverRequestMiddleware, rehydrateMiddleware)
    )
  );
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After spending a couple of hours researching and doing some trial and error, I've finally found a work-around for this warning.

As per [github comment](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-toolkit/issues/2008#issuecomment-1032025129) you can add the below lines at the very beginning of your React/Redux project:

```
// eslint-disable-next-line
import Symbol_observable from 'symbol-observable';
```

It seems that for a weird reason my project does not polyfill the Symbol observable so if we add the npm library [symbol-observable](https://www.npmjs.com/package/symbol-observable) the warning is getting disappeared.

The good news is that trying the latest `create-react-app` project with template `redux` (e.g. `npx create-react-app my-app --template redux`), the issue is not there anymore. So it should have to do with a combination of versions as @markerikson mentioned within my project specifically.

Answer (score 3):

This is a brand-new check and warning that was just added to the Redux DevTools code in the last few days:

https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-devtools/issues/1002#issuecomment-1011097465

If you're still using Redux 4.0.5 or earlier, it's possible that upgrading to Redux 4.1.x would fix this warning (because 4.1.0 removed the use of the `symbol-observable` polyfill).

That said, you *should* really be using [our official Redux Toolkit package](https://redux.js.org/tutorials/fundamentals/part-8-modern-redux) to set up the Redux store and write your Redux logic, rather than using the original core `createStore` method directly.

Comment: A quick note here: This is still doesn't work for me but at least I am the right direction to find it out. Thank you @markerikson for all the support that you are giving  . Redux toolkit seems awesome and the right way to go. Keep up the good work.

Comment: I am having the same issue here updating to 4.1.2 did not fix it, were you able to find more about this issue?

Comment: Hello @WildThing, it doesn't work for me either. Things that I've tried so far:
1. Updating redux to the latest version (currently 4.1.2) 
2. Replacing the `createStore` with `@reduxjs/toolkit` and `configureStore`
3. Removing the package:  `@redux-devtools/extension` as it is included in @reduxjs/toolkit
But still no luck.

Comment: The message is coming from within the actual Redux DevTools Extension in the browser itself. Try updating that to the latest version.

Comment: Still doesn't work. I am using latest chrome extension (current latest `3.0.9`)

Comment: At this point I would recommend filing a new issue with a reproduction on the Redux DevTools repo and get help directly from the maintainer.

Comment: Yes, I agree. I hope I will have some time to create a clean repo with the reproduction of this.

Comment: 2 months later, I still have this issue and could not resolve it.. any updates with you guys?

Comment: I've finally found a work-around for this. Just posted it as an answer to this question.